# TABLE ACCESS FULL in Oracle execution plan

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I have been tasked to find out the SELECT statement for an explain plan

```
------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation              | Name     |
------------------------------------------
| 0  | SELECT STATEMENT       |          |
| 1  |  HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI  |          |
| 2  |   VIEW                 | VW_NSO_1 |
| 3  |    HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI|          | 
| 4  |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PART     |
| 5  |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | ORDERS   |
| 6  |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | CUSTOMER |
------------------------------------------
```

I am able to find the select statement from Id 0-5 but what does the line 6 mean?
This is what I have managed to figure out so far I can't get where the last sentence comes into play.

```
select *
from customer c join orders o
on c.custkey = o.custkey
where o_totalprice
not in 
(select p_retailprice
from part p join orders o
on orders.o_custkey >= 0 and 0.1*o_totalprice >= 0)
```

I can't get where the last sentence comes into play?

Comment: Well, you are selecting from the table `customer`, why are you surprised that it shows up in the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
select *
from customer c join orders o
on c.custkey = o.custkey
where o_totalprice
not in 
(select p_retailprice
from part p join orders o
on orders.o_custkey >= 0 and 0.1*o_totalprice >= 0)
```

And your explain plan is

```
------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation              | Name     |
------------------------------------------
| 0  | SELECT STATEMENT       |          |
| 1  |  HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI  |          |
| 2  |   VIEW                 | VW_NSO_1 |
| 3  |    HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI|          | 
| 4  |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PART     |
| 5  |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | ORDERS   |
| 6  |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | CUSTOMER |
------------------------------------------
```

In your case, this is what happens:

1. You are getting all the records from both customer and orders that match the condition based on the custkey field.
2. Your predicate information is delimiting the output to those where o_totalprice ( by the way it should clarified for reading easiness where this field is coming from, although I guess is from orders table ) is not part of the dataset retrieved from the subquery.
3. the subquery is getting all values of p_retailprice that match the join between part and orders using orders.o_custkey >= 0 and 0.1*o_totalprice >= 0

Getting this in consideration the CBO is:

- Accessing ( Line 6 ) by TABLE FULL SCAN the table CUSTOMER, which is logical as you are getting all fields from the table and probably you have no index over custkey.
- Making a HASH SEMI JOIN ( line 3 ) between PARTS and ORDERS. In general, a semi join is used for an in or exists clause, and the join stops as soon as the exists condition or the in condition is satisfied.
- The HASH JOIN ANTI of line 1 is when the optimizer push the join predicate into a view, normally when an anti join ( not in ) is in place. This is then join to the CUSTOMER TABLE in line 6.
- You are filtering only in the right table of the join ( ORDERS ) that is why the access are reflecting that.

This is just an overview of your execution plan and the reasons why the CBO is using those access paths.